# returning corresponding array values for use in wordpress loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am performing the below code within wordpress. To give a brief outline of what I am trying to achieve: I query the database to return a list of exercises, values (reps and sets for exercises) are assigned to them and stored in $_SESSION in the following array structure.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ExerciseID] => 75
        [Sets] => 
        [Reps] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ExerciseID] => 690
        [Sets] => 3
        [Reps] => 3
    )

)
```

The code: I return the exercise ID's into a array so I can then run a WP_Query using them. When the results are returned I need them to display the reps and sets (the variables that are in the array) with the exercise.

```
<?php
$ids = array();
if(empty($_SESSION['collection']))
{echo"<p>There's nothing in your collection, an add some by searching above</p>";}
else
{
foreach($_SESSION['collection'] as $el)
{
 $ids[] = $el['ExerciseID'];
}
}
// START OF THE QUERY USING THE EXERCISE ID'S FOR DISPLAYING IN THE COLLECTION
$the_query = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => $ids, 'post_type' => 'exercise',   'posts_per_page' =>'100')); ?>


<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


<div class="thumbnail">

<div class="caption" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">

  <h5>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </h5>
  <?php the_post_thumbnail('collection_thumb'); ?>
  </div>
 <br />
  <form action="" method="post">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-m" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">Delete</button>
</form>
</div>
```

I am struggling matching the reps and sets to be displayed along side the exercise that has been queried.

Apologies for the poor explanation, by clicking on a exercise on this [website](http://www.elementdevelopment.co.uk/rehabguru_wp/?unonce=c3a40f085f&uformid=15&s=uwpsfsearchtrg&taxo%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=body%20part&taxo%5B0%5D%5Bopt%5D=3&taxo%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=exercise%20types&taxo%5B1%5D%5Bopt%5D=3) and adding it to the collection hopefully you can see what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: If you can, I would set the array index to the exercise ID. This will allow you to easily call `$_SESSION['collection'][$exerciseID]['sets']` and `$_SESSION['collection'][$exerciseID]['reps']` respectively. Otherwise you will have to iterate over the collection array to find the proper ID.

Comment: So this is my array creation code `  if (isset($_POST['exerciseExpand'])) {
   $_SESSION['collection'][] = array('ExerciseID' => $_POST['ExerciseID'],'Sets' => $_POST['Sets'],'Reps' => $_POST['Reps']);
      }
}` how can I give this the ExerciseID as the index?

Comment: `if ( isset( $_POST['exerciseExpand'] ) ) { $_SESSION['collection'][$_POST['ExerciseID']] = array( 'ExerciseID' => $_POST['ExerciseID'], 'Sets' => $_POST['Sets'], 'Reps' => $_POST['Reps'] ); }` - Note: All I did was define the index instead of leaving it as `[]`

Comment: Awesome so now my array structure is Array
(
    [75] => Array
        (
            [ExerciseID] => 75
            [Sets] => 
            [Reps] => 
        )

)
how can I pull the reps and sets that correspond with the ExerciseID into the wordpress loop? 
Really appreciate your help saved me hours.

Comment: No worries, this is in my first response. `$_SESSION['collection'][$exerciseID]['sets']` you would have to define `$exerciseID` with the appropriate exerciseID. I would assume this is the post id for excersise post type. You should be able to use `get_the_ID()`

Comment: Ok great so $reps = $_SESSION['collection'][$ExerciseID]['Sets']; works well when I hard code it - would it be possible for you to help me with this bit so I can perform the foreach and ensure that they are input into the wordpress loop so they are assigned to the correct ExerciseID

Comment: Also this has been the answer so can you make it one and I will mark it as answered. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the array index to the `ExerciseID` like so:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['exerciseExpand'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['collection'][$_POST['ExerciseID']] = array( 
        'ExerciseID' => $_POST['ExerciseID'],
        'Sets' => $_POST['Sets'],
        'Reps' => $_POST['Reps'] 
    );
}
```

This will allow you to use the data as:
`$_SESSION['collection'][$exerciseID]['sets']` and `$_SESSION['collection'][$exerciseID]['reps']` respectively.